newbie with unusual network config question
I have an unusual (to me) networking question. I have traditionally been a linux user but not really setup things myself, so I'm learning but I apologize in advance for my ignorance.
I'm setting up a rack-mounted cluster in my basement. I have a management node ("mgmt") with a RAID disk array that I want to use ocfs2 on, to mount universal storage in the same spot across the cluster. I have 12x worker nodes ("n01" through "n12"). I'm using ubuntu server 24.04.01 LTS on all nodes. I currently have everything booting to gnome desktop, but obviously before doing work I will disable that and just boot everything to CLI.
Regarding network configuration:

The head node "mgmt" has 4x GbE connections all working fine connecting to my LAN and the internet. No problems here!
All nodes ("mgmt" and "n01" through "n12") have 2x sfp+ connections going to an Arista DCS-7050S-64 switch. The switch and cables were all tested by the hardware vendor.
The goal is to have really fast communication on the internal network (mgmt and n01-n12), and to have external access for the worker nodes (n01-n12) route through the mgmt node. The internal network is for compute communications. The external access can be slow because it is only for periodic updates and such.

So, for the internal network, I setup the network manually using IPv4. I set the management node's sfp connections 1/2 as 192.168.10.1/192.168.10.2, and the various worker nodes n## with sfp connections 1/2 as 192.168.10.1##/192.168.10.2## just so I could remember it all. I set netmask as 255.255.255.0 everywhere, which to my understanding means that the first 3x 8-bit values "192.168.10" portion of the IP addresses will all be assumed constant, and the last 1x 8-bit value (the RH value of the host portion) will vary by host. I set the first sfp connection on each machine to a gateway of the mgmt node sfp#1 connection, and the second sfp connection on each machine to a gateway of the mgmt node sfp#2 connection.
I can ping the local sfp connections #1 or #2 on any node. I cannot ping anything between the other nodes and the mgmt node. I suppose the question is, what am I doing incorrectly?
Update with Requested Info:
mgmt:~> ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno4 proto static metric 102
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno1 proto static metric 103
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno3 proto static metric 105
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno2 proto static metric 108
default via 192.168.10.1 dev ens15f0 proto static metric 20106
default via 192.168.10.2 dev ens15f1 proto static metric 20109
192.168.0.0/24 dev eno4 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.204 metric 102
192.168.0.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.201 metric 103
192.168.0.0/24 dev eno3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.203 metric 105
192.168.0.0/24 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.202 metric 108
192.168.10.0/24 dev ens15f0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.1 metric 106
192.168.10.0/24 dev ens15f1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.2 metric 109

n01:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.10.1 dev eno1np0 proto static metric 20101
default via 192.168.10.201 dev enp96s0f1np1 proto static metric 20102
192.168.10.0/24 dev eno1np0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.101 metric 101
192.168.10.0/24 dev enp96s0f1np1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.201 metric 102

I installed ubuntu server. I used sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop to add gnome desktop to diagnose and fix a couple other items, which by my understanding can be disabled in a straightforward manner to just have my machines boot to command line without the overhead.
RESOLVED:
After getting a serial-to-USB cable and plugging into the Arista switch, I found an error message saying the Mellanox transcievers I was sold with the switch were "unqualified." I returned them and got Cisco transcievers. Everything "just worked." Thanks!

First observation, you state you’re using Ubuntu 24.04 Server, but you talk about booting to Gnome Desktop, which you plan to disable later. So you actually installed a Desktop version and not a Server version. This means networking is managed differently. Next, it appears all interfaces are within the same subnet: 192.168.10.xxx, and you say you can ping each interface from some other host but not between nodes. This is confusing to me. I would check your router to make sure it’s configured correctly. If so, you should be able to ping any host within the same subnet.

Please edit/update your question with the output of ip route on one of your nodes and on the mgmt host. I’m suspecting there might be a routing conflict to your default gateway, since both interfaces on each host are in the same subnet and would typically have the same gateway. You may have to change the metric.

Thank you so much for the help!

I think there might be some misunderstanding w/ how to setup a network. For example, on your node, you have two devices, both in the 192.168.10.xxx subnet, but with two gateways, 192.168.10.1 & 192.168.10.201. This can't happen. Please edit/update w/ what your intentions are. I feel that you want two interfaces on the host that are segregated for some reason. Why? If so, then each interface should be on different subnets. For example: 192.168.10.xxx/24 for eno1np0 & 192.168.20.xxx/24 for enp96s0f1np1 , each with their own respective gateway: 192.168.10.1 & 192.168.20.1.

Also, to make sure I understand your setup, is the mgmt node and the worker nodes all separate bare metal devices? I feel like they are, because you state you're physically connecting SPF cables to an Arista DCS-7050S-64 switch. Then this switch is connected to your router, correct?

Hi! Sorry for the gap, family emergency. I undoubtedly misunderstand networks! I have 13 separate machines, nothing virtual, they are all rack-mounted. The management node is a 4U storage server and the worker compute nodes are 4x nodes per 2U chassis. I'm not doing anything fancy like MAAS (yet), just separate installs on each physically/logically separate node's local SATA3 drive. My intention is to have a high speed internal network between the management node and compute nodes for parallel calculations, but to access it through a separate external network going through the management node.

Each separate node has 2x sfp ports. The 48-port switch has enough ports for the (1 mgmt + 12 compute) = 13 nodes to utilize 2x13 = 26 of those 48 ports, which I guess I assumed was for link aggregation for speed or bandwidth or latency or whatever. I've never worked with anything newer than RJ45 GbE aside from an end user of infiniband. I've tried finding a local to pay for deployment help without luck, I'd happily pay someone for the help. I think I'm just trying to get the internal LAN inbetween nodes working now; compute node WAN access routed through mgmt would be nice for updates though.
